# $\tan(\arg(1+ix))=x$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Let $\log$ be the inverse function to $e^x$ with branch cut on the negative real axis, and define $\arg z=\Im\log(z)$. The basic relation between the $\arg$ function and the arctangent is $\arg(x+iy)=\arctan(\frac yx)$, and given that $\Im\log(az)=\Im[\log a+\log z]=\Im\log z$ when $a$ is real, this relation can be reduced to the identity

$$\tan(\arg(1+ix))=x,\quad x\in\Bbb R.$$

The $\tan$ function is defined via the complex exponential as $\tan x=-i\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}$. How does one prove this identity?

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{i\arg z}=e^{i\Im\log z}=e^{\log z-\Re\log z}=\frac z{|z|},$$

where $e^{\Re\log z}=|z|$ because $|e^{x+iy}|=\sqrt{e^{x+iy}e^{x-iy}}=\sqrt{e^{2x}}=e^x$. Thus

$$\tan(\arg z)=-i\frac{e^{i\arg z}-e^{-i\arg z}}{e^{i\arg z}+e^{-i\arg z}}=-i\frac{z^2-|z|^2}{z^2+|z|^2},$$

and since $(1+ix)^2=1+2ix-x^2$ and $|1+ix|^2=1+x^2$ this works out to

$$\tan(\arg(1+ix))=-i\frac{(1+2ix-x^2)-(1+x^2)}{(1+2ix-x^2)+(1+x^2)}=-i\frac{2ix-2x^2}{2+2ix}=x,$$

as desired.